# Get an array from SpookyJs to Meteor

Tags: meteor, casperjs, spookyjs

After a lot of hard work, my SpookyJS script works as I should and I got my spoils of war, an array of values I want to use to query my Collection in my Meteor app, but I have a huge problem.

I can't find a way to call any Meteor specific methods from spooky...

So my code is like this for the spooky.on function:

```
spooky.on('fun', function (courses) {
  console.log(courses);
  // Meteor.call('edxResult', courses); // doesn't work...
});
```

The console.log gives me the result I want:

```
[ 'course-v1:MITx+6.00.2x_3+1T2015',
'HarvardX/CS50x3/2015',
'course-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS101x.2+1T2015',
'MITx/6.00.1x_5/1T2015' ]
```

What I need is a way to call a Meteor.method with courses as my argument or a way to get access to the array in the current Meteor.method, after spookyjs finished it's work (Sadly I have no idea how to check whether spooky is finished)

My last idea would be to give the Meteor.method a callback function and store the array in the session or something, but that sounds like extremly bad design, there has to be a better way, I hope.

I am extremly proud of my little ghost, so any help to get it the last few pieces over the finish line would be extremly appricated.

Comment: how did you added spooky into meteor ? `meteor npm install --save spooky` ? i got that but when i make the `try` statement it says it cant find spooky. Do you have any example ?